# Retrieve separate elements from a mySQL array field and iterate to create map

Tags: java, php, mysql, geocoding

Because I'm using a map interface in Limesurvey, my mySQL database populates a "text" field in my table 'geo' like this:

```
27.059125784374068;-102.65625;CITY;STATE;COUNTRY;
```

The code I use in the presentation map looks for specific lat/lon information to iterate through the placemarks:

```
$encodedString = ""; 
$x = 0; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `geo`");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
        if ( $x == 0 )
        {
             $separator = "";
        }
        else
        {
             $separator = "****";
        }
        $encodedString = $encodedString.$separator.
        "<p class='content'>
        <br><b>Lon:</b> ".$row[0].
        "<br><b>Lat:</b> ".$row[1].
        "<br><b>SiteName: </b>".$row[2].
        "<br><b>Country: </b>".$row[4].
        "<br><b>PI: </b>".$row[5].
        "</p>&&&".$row[1]."&&&".$row[2];
        $x = $x + 1;
    }
```

Am I making my life harder by trying to extract the lat/lon values from geoBlob? Is there a way to use the text field as it is?

I'm extracting the lon value like this:

```
$result =  mysql_query("SELECT geoBlob FROM `geo`");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($row as $k=>$v)
    {
        $breakEmUp = explode(";", $v);
        $lon = $breakEmUp[0]; 
        $arr[] = $lon;
    }
    $lonArray = join (", " , $arr);
```

But I don't know how to put the pieces together.

Getting way over my head here. Uncle! Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Better you put each your text into differrent field, so make it easier than you must use string separator.

Comment: Yes, I thought of that and updated my table with the fields I need (lat, lon, etc.), but I'm (noob alert!) not sure how to write php code to update the table with data extracted from the text array field. Tried a bunch of things, but never got it to work.